# aws athena query to get count greater than certain number

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

How do I get `count` greater than an certain number with AWS Athena query?

```sql
SELECT
    concat(cast(date as varchar),' ',substr(time,1,5)) as datetime,
    requestip,
    count(*) as count 
FROM "tk_logs"."btb-cf-aug-2023" 
WHERE
        uri like '/topics/%'
    and cast(concat(cast(date as varchar),' ',substr(time,1,5)) as varchar) >= '2023-08-07 00:59' 
    and count >=100
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 1 asc
```

I tried above query but got error

```
 Column 'count' cannot be resolved or requester is not authorized to access requested resources
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is likely caused by `count >=100` because it is an aggregated total. Trying moving it to a `HAVING` like this:

```sql
SELECT
    concat(cast(date as varchar),' ',substr(time,1,5)) as datetime,
    requestip,
    count(*) as count 
FROM "tk_logs"."btb-cf-aug-2023" 
WHERE
        uri like '/topics/%'
    and cast(concat(cast(date as varchar),' ',substr(time,1,5)) as varchar) >= '2023-08-07 00:59' 
GROUP BY 1,2
HAVING count(*) >= 100
ORDER BY 1 asc
```